# Adding error bar to scatter plot, existing examples don't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Hello I am trying to add an error bar to the following scatter plot:

```py
(x, y) = self.rig_parameters["image_size"]
        
disparity_image = np.array(image)

locations = np.where(disparity_image > error_bound)
values = disparity_image[locations]
        
plt.xlim(0, x)
plt.ylim(y, 0)
plt.scatter(locations[1], locations[0], values, vmin = error_bound, vmax = 256)      
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

But the colorbar is not scaled correctly, it doesn't look like the plot uses color as a scale either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code as follows:

```py
colormap = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma')
sp = plt.scatter(locations[1], locations[0], values, vmin=error_bound, vmax=256, cmap=colormap)
plt.colorbar(sp)
```

Choose the color scheme you like the most, take a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#overview).